# Checking for a character being in a string multiple times

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Ran into a little problem, I want to check if a certain character is in a string multiple times. This is the string:

```
string str01 = "?????????? ??????????, ??????????, ???????? !!!";
```

Now I want to check if the character **"?"** is in the string at least 10 times. I tried using an array but the spaces would trick that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helpfully, `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so you can use some LINQ:

```
var result = str01.Count(x => x == '?') > 10;
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ex0hmN).

Answer (score 1):

For very (very) long strings you should **not** use Enumerable.Count solutions because they evaluate the entire string (even if the first 10 characters are already question marks)

**Alternative**
Create an extension class which shortcuts the count if possible:

```
public static class AtLeastExtension
{
    public static bool AtLeast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T e, int Max)
    { 
        if (enumerable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enumerable));
        if (Max < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(Max));
        if (Max == 0) return true;

        int cnt = 0;
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
            if (object.Equals(item, e))
                if (++cnt >= Max) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var result = str01.AtLeast('?', 10);
```

Comment: You're *partially* right: you can't use `Count` (it's may be inefficient), but you *can* still use *Linq*: `Skip` + `Any` is a way out

Comment: to be an extension method (and `public` one), you, IMHO, should have included *validations*: what if `enumerable` is `null`? What if `item` within it is `null`? what if `Max == -1` (and aggravating the test case `enumerable` is *empty*)? Your current code does solve the problem (ten `'?'`), but it's a dangerous implementation in *general case*.

Comment: was supposed to be just a proof of concept but you're right most of the time the code will be just copy&pasted as is. Added guard clauses and fixed comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **LINQ** like this:

```
int count = source.Count(f => f == '?');
```

And than you can compare count variable with value that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to keep your array approach, you could use the string.Replace() method to take out the whitespace and commas:

```
str01 = str01.Replace(" ", "");
str01 = str01.Replace(",", "");
```

But the other solutions using LINQ are probably better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just assure that `?` appears at least `10` times you can use *Linq*:

```
  string source = "?????????? ??????????, ??????????, ???????? !!!";
  int repeatAtLeast = 10;

  bool appears = source
    .Where(c => c == '?')
    .Skip(repeatAtLeast - 1)
    .Any();
```

for *long* strings `Where` + `Skip` + `Any` can be *more efficient* than `Count(c => c == '?')`: we stop when 10th `'?'` has been found, and do not need to scan the entire string.